# Back Key Doesn't Work in Unity3d Remote

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Hi Everybody I'm Using Unity3D 4.5.5 and Unity Remote 4 on My Android Device. When I Run My project in My Phone Back Button Works OK but When I Connect My Android Phone Using Remote app It's Not Working. Am I Doing Anything Wrong or It's not Support That?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Unity Remote manual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote4.html):

> The following data from device is streamed back to the editor:
>
> - Touch input
> - Accelerometer
> - Gyroscope
> - Device camera streams

System buttons aren't listed, so I wouldn't necessarily expect them to work.

Generally speaking, you would bind that with `KeyCode.Escape` (you can use `KeyCode.Menu` for the settings button). If it's working on-device, you should be fine.

Comment: I'm Using KeyCode.Escape in My Code But Older Version of Unity Remote Works With this How Come New Version Doesn't Support that?